# Set parent for custom post type archive rewrite url

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have 2 custom post types

**Offices**

```
    register_post_type('offices',
        [
            'labels' => [
                'name' => __( 'Offices' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Office' )
            ],
            'description' => 'Our Office.',
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => false,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-building',
            'support' => ['title', 'custom_fields', 'page-attributes']
        ]
    );
```

**Office members**

```
   //Team Members
    register_post_type( 'office_members',
        [
            'labels' => [
                'name' => __( 'Team Members' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Team Member' )
            ],
            'description' => 'Team members for offices.',
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive' => 'offices/([^/]+)/members',
            'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=offices',
            'support' => ['title', 'custom_fields', 'page-attributes']
        ]
    );
```

I want the following urls to work

`example.com/offices` - Shows the office archive page

`example.com/offices/([^/]+)` - Show the single office page

`example.com/offices/([^/]+)/members` - Show the members archive page where parent is the office

`example.com/offices/([^/]+)/members/([^/]+)` - Show the single member page

I have the following rewrite rules for the office members

```
    add_permastruct('office_members', '/offices/%office%/members/%office_members%', false,  ['walk_dirs' => false]);
    add_rewrite_tag('%office_members%', '([^/]+)', 'office_members=');
    add_rewrite_rule('^offices/([^/]+)/members/([^/]+)?','index.php?office_members=$matches[2]','top');
```

All of my urls work except for the members archive page. It loads the template file `archive-office_members.php` which is great, but it doesn't detect the parent office in the url. So instead of it only showing members for that office it just shows all members.

How can I set my url so that it shows the members archive page, but only shows members based on the `office` in the url, and so all 4 of my urls work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to register the `%office%` rewrite tag:

```php
// First, add the rewrite tag.
add_rewrite_tag( '%office%', '([^/]+)', 'post_type=office_members&office_name=' );

// Then call add_permastruct().
add_permastruct( 'office_members', ... );
```

Then, add the custom `office_name` arg to the *public* query vars so that WordPress reads/parses it from the URL:

```php
add_filter( 'query_vars', function ( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'office_name';
    return $vars;
} );
```

And use the `pre_get_posts` hook to load the correct `office_members` posts that are children of the `offices` post with the slug in the `office_name` arg:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() &&
        is_post_type_archive( 'office_members' ) &&
        $slug = $query->get( 'office_name' )
    ) {
        $arg = ( false !== strpos( $slug, '/' ) ) ? 'offices' : 'name';
        $ids = get_posts( "post_type=offices&{$arg}=$slug&fields=ids" );

        if ( ! empty( $ids ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_parent', $ids[0] );
        }
    }
} );
```

Now the members archive page should show the proper posts, but we need to fix the pagination for that page, and for that reason, we can use the `parse_request` hook:

```php
add_action( 'parse_request', function ( $wp ) {
    if ( isset( $wp->query_vars['paged'] ) &&
        preg_match( '#^offices/([^/]+)/members/page/(\d+)#', $wp->request, $matches )
    ) {
        $wp->query_vars['paged']       = $matches[2];
        $wp->query_vars['office_name'] = $matches[1];
    }
} );
```

And btw, you've got a typo in your `register_post_type()` args: You used `support`, but the correct arg name is `supports` (note the second "s").